# Add Sub Module Error Message

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am trying to follow instructions on the following [link](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-submodules.html) to add a submodule on an already existing path(repo/SubContainer) that contains other sub-modules but each time I add it I get error message "SubContainer already exists in the index".
My Folder Structure:

```
repo
  --SubContainer
    --Sub1
```

Comment: The folder must not yet exist. - Is there already a submodule defined? - YOu need to run Submodule update and select init.

Comment: Yes but the new sub module doesn't appear. What shall I do? How can I clone the submodule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add a submodule to a folder where another submodule exists. `SubContainer already exists in the index` means that a submodule in the place you provided is already part of the index. Each submodule has to have its own folder. like this:

```
repo
  --SubContainer
    --Sub1
    --Sub2
```

So if you add a submodule, you have to add it in path `SubContainer/SubX`. The corresponding command-line command would be `git submodule add <Submodule URL> SubContainer/SubX`. It does not suffice to provide the `SubContainer` path; git will **not** automatically create a folder for the submodule in the SubContainer folder. A new folder is only created if you do not provide a path at all.

Comment: Thanks @Kowsky so much